# Submitting HTTP request from HTML to AWS API gateway

Tags: html, json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a HTML form with a button which allows me to send HTTP requests in "text/plain" or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format.

```
text/plain: 
stateMachineArn=arn:aws:states:us-east-1:0111111165:stateMachine:MyStateMachine
name=ExecutionName
first_name=test
last_name=test2

application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
stateMachineArn=arn:aws:states:us-east-1:0111111165:stateMachine:MyStateMachine&name=ExecutionName&first_name=test&last_name=test2
```

But AWS API gateway receives only JSON format by default ("input" has to be escaped)

```
{
    "input": "{\"first_name\" : \"test\",\"last_name\" : \"test2\"}",
    "name": "ExecutionName",
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:0111111165:stateMachine:MyStateMachine"
}
```

How can I convert either formats to the above JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a form like this:

```
<form>

  <input type="stateMachineArn" name="stateMachineArn" id="stateMachineArn" />
  <input type="name" name="name" id="name" />
  <label for="first_name">First name</label>
  <input type="first_name" name="first_name" id="first_name" />

  <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
  <input type="last_name" name="last_name" id="last_name" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can handle submissions in js like this and log the response like you did - don´t know if that´s what you are doing:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const data = new FormData(event.target);

  const value = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());

  console.log({ value });
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

At this point if you want to convert data object to json before sending it somewhere or just to log it, have you tried this?

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Or this?

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(value ));
```

EDIT

To send the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservices/PodcastService.asmx/CreateMarkers",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    error: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I submit it JSON as part of the body of the request?

Comment: You can do an ajax request with that payload. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my jsfiddle page? It is saying "data is undefined". I tried defining "data" again but doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/janitor500/L2hudrj6/31/

Comment: Yes, I can take a look at it. It´s logging:
{
  value: {
    executionname: "123",
    first_name: "123",
    last_name: "123",
    stateMachineArn: "123"
  }
}
Wasn´t this what you asked - converting it to json? 
You can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I checked your fiddle. Ajax request should be moved inside handleSubmit just below the console.log({value}) and you should pass JSON.stringify(value)  to that request instead of data: JSON.stringify(data)
At that point, log the response and errors and run it to check where you are at.